# auto scroll to marker in svg image ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, autoscroll

I want scroll to `x=350` and `y=220` when my screen is load.

My default screen :

[image]

I want :

[image]

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`scrollTo(x, y, duration)`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#scrollTo) method like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.content.scrollTo(350, 220, 500); // Duration is 500 ms
  }
}
```